# After upgraded as the Ubunut 22.04.1 LTS, icons is not showing properlly and could not install MS teams

Tags: 22.04, desktop-icons

[Microsoft teams is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFCKL.png)

[Desktop icons is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVszh.png)

Comment: Upgraded to 22.04 from what exactly?

Comment: From 20.04 to 22.04.